# Conditional nav in app.vue depending on user logged in state from main.js

Tags: vue.js

I want to show a different navigation in app.vue depending on user is signed 
  in or not. i came complicated solutions, isn't there a simple if else solution or pass function from main.js to vue.js? thanks in advance

```
#main.js
Vue.loggedIn=true

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

#App.vue

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-if="Vue.loggedIn" id="nav">
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link> | 
      <router-link to="/register">Register</router-link> | 
      <router-link to="/login">Login</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/profile">profile</router-link>
    </div>
    <div v-else id="nav">
      ...
      ..
    </div>
    <router-view/>
      </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Why are you storing `loggedIn` in the global `Vue` rather than in your instance's `data`?

Comment: I've done that too.  App.vue doesn't change the nav. they're not linked i guess..trying to figure that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, App should use its own `data` items, so if you define `loggedIn` as one, you should get the behavior you want. Since it's your top-level module, I don't expect you want to pass it in as a prop, although that would work, too.

```js
const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      loggedIn: false
    };
  },
  template: '#app-template',
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => this.loggedIn = true, 2500);
  }
};

new Vue({
  render(h) {
    return h(App);
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>

<template id="app-template">
  <div id="nav">
    <template v-if="loggedIn">
      This is the logged in one
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      This is the not logged in one.
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```